# Giving SystemMessage/Context to ConversationalRetrievalChain and ConversationBufferMemory in Lang Chain

Tags: python, openai-api, py-langchain

I'm trying to build a chatbot that can chat about pdfs, and I got it working with memory using `ConversationBufferMemory` and `ConversationalRetrievalChain` like in this example. https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/chat_vector_db.html

Now I'm trying to give the AI some special instructions to talk like a pirate (just for testing to see if it is receiving the instructions). I think this is meant to be a `SystemMessage`, or something with a prompt template?

I've tried everything I have found, but all the examples in the documentation are for `ConversationChain` and I end up having problems with. So far the only thing that hasn't had any errors is this:

```
template = """Given the following conversation respond to the best of your ability in a pirate voice and end every sentence with Ay Ay Matey
Chat History:
{chat_history}
Follow Up Input: {question}
Standalone question:"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["chat_history", "question"], template=template
)
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key='chat_history', return_messages=True, output_key='answer')
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0), vectorstore.as_retriever(), PROMPT, memory=memory, return_source_documents=True)
```

It still doesn't have any effect on the results, so I don't know if it is doing anything at all. I also think it's the wrong approach, and I should be using `SystemMessage`s (maybe on the memory, not the qa), but nothing I try from the documentation works and I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3):

##### Edit: 26th November, 2023

An exception will occur with the demo: `document_variable_name context was not found in llm_chain input_variables: ['chat_history', 'question'] (type=value_error)`

This is due the the missing prompt context. try injecting context like below:

```py
template = """Given the following conversation respond to the best of your ability in a pirate voice and end every sentence with Ay Ay Matey
Context: {context}
Chat History: {chat_history}
Follow Up Input: {question}
Standalone question:"""

PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["context", "chat_history", "question"], 
    template=template
)
```

---

##### Initial Answer:

You can't pass `PROMPT` directly as a param on `ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm()`. Try using the `combine_docs_chain_kwargs` param to pass your `PROMPT`. See the below example with ref to your provided sample code:

```py
template = """Given the following conversation respond to the best of your ability in a pirate voice and end every sentence with Ay Ay Matey
Chat History:
{chat_history}
Follow Up Input: {question}
Standalone question:"""

PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["chat_history", "question"], 
    template=template
)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
    memory_key='chat_history', 
    return_messages=True, 
    output_key='answer'
)

qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=OpenAI(temperature=0),
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    memory=memory,
    return_source_documents=True,
    combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": PROMPT}
)
```

Then get the result:

```py
result = qa({"question": query})
```

Comment: looks like you mentioned a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76240871/how-do-i-add-memory-to-retrievalqa-from-chain-type-or-how-do-i-add-a-custom-pr

Did you figure out the sending your custom `PROMPT` through `ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm()`?

Comment: I get "document_variable_name context was not found in llm_chain input_variables: ['chat_history', 'question'] (type=value_error)" - any clue?

Comment: @wxh same issue happening to me as well. could not find any solyution till now

Comment: @SKR - no luck so far...

Comment: That might be due to missing prompt context. As I mentioned, the demo was ref from the original author sample in the question. Try injecting the context variable inside the prompt. See my edited answer as a demo. @SKR

Comment: Please see the edited answer @wxh

Answer (score 1):

If you stumbled upon this page while looking for ways to pass system message to a prompt passed to ConversationalRetrievalChain using ChatOpenAI, you can try wrapping `SystemMessagePromptTemplate` in a `ChatPromptTemplate`. As mentioned in @Rijoanul Hasan Shanto's answer, make sure to include `{context}` into a template string so that it's recognized as the context. For example:

```py
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import SystemMessagePromptTemplate, ChatPromptTemplate, HumanMessagePromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain

messages = [
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{context} talk like a pirate"),
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{question}")
]
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages=messages)

qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(), 
    retriever=vector_store.as_retriever(), 
    combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": prompt}
)

result = qa({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
```

This is useful if you want to your bot to be aware of say, current date. In that case you can pass the current date into the prompt as follows:

```py
from datetime import datetime
current_date = f'Current date: {datetime.now().strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y")}.'
# list of templates to create the chat template
messages = [
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{context} "+current_date),
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{question}")
]
# define prompt to pass to qa chain
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages=messages)

qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(), 
    retriever=vector_store.as_retriever(), 
    combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": prompt}
)

result = qa({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
```