# How can I add SystemMessage (or a persona) into from ConversationalRetrievalChain

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I am using `chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm, retriever= retriever, memory = memory)` and this works well with conversational memory and stuff. However, I am unable to give it a set list of instructions to follow. Essentially, I need to combine the prior code with something like this:

```
messages = [
    # System Message -- tell it instructions, how to make sense of content
    # give me example
    SystemMessage(content="You are a helpful assistant."), # develop persona to agent, ask it what should it do, course coordinator, for ex:...(few shot learning), in case something is not clear ask question back to me, 1) major, 2) classes taken, 3) 
    HumanMessage(content="Hi AI, how are you today?"),
    AIMessage(content="I'm great thank you. How can I help you?"),
]
```

I have tried following the instructions on this post: [Giving SystemMessage/Context to ConversationalRetrievalChain and ConversationBufferMemory in Lang Chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178954/giving-systemmessage-context-to-conversationalretrievalchain-and-conversationbuf)

However, when I implement this, my code runs very, very slow and gives erroneous responses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.